# IF statements with strings from PyTesseract

Tags: python, if-statement, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm a complete novice at all of this (including Python), but I need it for a problem I'm working on. I've annotated my code so hopefully it's easy to see what I've done.
I'm trying to read a section of my screen in realtime, with whatever text is detected by the OCR being compared to all of the if/else statements. When it matches, I want it to print a string. Currently, the realtime OCR detection is working, but it doesn't go through the if/else statements to print the correct strings. I know this as print(tesstr) gives correct outputs but the current code doesn't produce any output.

```
# cv2.cvtColor takes a numpy ndarray as an argument
import numpy as nm

import pytesseract

# importing OpenCV
import cv2

from PIL import ImageGrab


def imToString():

    while(True):

        # ImageGrab-To capture the screen image in a loop.
        # Bbox used to capture a specific area.
        cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(267, 225, 344, 257))

        # Inverted the image for it to be easily
        # read by the OCR and obtained the output String.
        tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            cv2.bitwise_not(nm.array(cap)),
            lang='eng',
            config = '--psm 7')
        if (tesstr == '1'):
            print('Ace')
        elif (tesstr == '2'):
            print('Queen')
        elif (tesstr == '3'):
            print('King')
        ...
# Calling the function
imToString()
```

Comment: You can print the output before if statements and check if it really the same string you are expecting. It can read "1" as "1 " with a space character

Comment: Try to print len(tesstr), it might be that your string contains whitespace and therefore your comparison fails

Comment: Thanks, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I've finally done it.

The problem was due to a non-unicode character being printed alongside my output. I still have no clue as to why it's doing that, but the working code is below. Any ideas as to why would be appreciated but it's not too concerning.

```
# cv2.cvtColor takes a numpy ndarray as an argument
import numpy as nm

# importing Tesseract for the OCR
import pytesseract

# importing OpenCV
import cv2

# importing ImageGrab to take the image of my screen
from PIL import ImageGrab

# importing re to santise my output to something readable by the if statement
import re

def replace_chars(text):

    # Replaces all characters instead of numbers from 'text'.
    # :param text: Text string to be filtered
    # :return: Resulting number
    
    list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', text)
    result_number = ''.join(list_of_numbers)
    return result_number


def imToString():

    while(True):

        # ImageGrab-To capture the screen image in a loop.
        # Bbox used to capture a specific area.
        cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(267, 225, 344, 257))

        # Reading from terminal window, so
        # inverted the image for it to be easily
        # read by the OCR engine.
        # --psm 7 as it reads input as single line.

        tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            cv2.bitwise_not(nm.array(cap)),
            lang='eng',
            config = '--psm 7')

        # Calling replace_chars to only read numbers
        tesstr = replace_chars(tesstr)
        print(tesstr)

        if (tesstr == '1'):
            print('Ace')
        elif (tesstr == '2'):
            print('Queen')
        elif (tesstr == '3'):
            print('King')        
        ...

# Calling the function
imToString()
```

replace_chars stolen from https://return2.net/python-tesseract-4-0-get-numbers-only/